# Start Menu icons broken after Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703) install

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, windows-10-v1703, live-tiles

I freshly installed **Windows 10**, and this is how the icons look on the **Start Menu**:

[image: Windows 10 Start Menu]

**Update: 04.05.2017**

Today, the icons seem missing. I assume that issue got fixed by itself.

[image]

Comment: What feature update do you have installed 1607 or 1703?

Comment: Where can we check that number?

Comment: If you run `winver` it will provide you the specific build.  You can also just indicate if you used a 1607 or 1703 ISO

Comment: It is 1703 Version.

Comment: Just to double-check, does that machine already have an active connection to the Internet?

Comment: Yes! there is an active Internet connection.

Comment: It may be prudent to open an elevated PowerShell window and reinstall the built-in apps for all users:  [Windows 10: Reinstall and Re-register Apps in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3175-reinstall-re-register-apps-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: And to confirm, when you say *"I freshly installed OS,"* did you actually perform a completely clean install of Windows 10 or did you choose to `Keep my files` instead?  While the function to `Keep my files` is a nice capability, it can potentially cause your Start Menu tiles to look like that since you might have shortcuts to applications that were removed during the Windows 10 version 1703 install process.  As another example, I had a `Windows Defender` tile on my Start Menu that looked just like the broken ones in your picture after the 1703 install because the new interfaced was changed.

Comment: I have made a completely clean install.

Comment: Interesting update.  One way or another, it is good to see that the problem has been alleviated.